# Dynamically load node module in a running node.js process

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, agent

Is there any way to load or attach node module to a already running node.js process. I want to attach a module which profiles node application, but how can i attach it dynamically without any change in user application.
Please share your opinion. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you ever find an answer do not forget to respond to your own question (if no one else does that is).

Comment: @jayarjo why did you delete your answer?

Comment: @JonasWilms 'cause I realized that what he was asking was different. He basically is looking to attach himself to the running script on the fly and profile the process in arbitrary way.

Comment: @jayarjo, exactly you got my point.

Answer (score 1):

You can `require()` modules at any time, everywhere. Also from the [NodeJS Inspector](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/).

Comment: I can't use this approach as I don't have permission to change user code. I want a solution which dynamically attach my module to the user application without any interference in user application's code.

Comment: Sure, have you clicked on that link?